# Role-playing game with office (developer) setting

Tags: game-recommendation

My coworkers and I were just wondering if there is any pen and paper role-playing game which features some software developer or at least office setting.
Does anyone know anything like that?

Comment: First I want to apologize for being lazy and therefore not reading the rules.
However; Thank you for your reply. I'll try to follow your advice an let your know as soon as I'm done. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. The question being closed does not give permission to break this rule. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Comment: Why is this considered a "shopping question"? It isn't inviting recommendations for 'the best', merely asking whether such a system exists? (I don't know of a single system revolving around coding...). [This meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6548/12454) seems to reflect the same sentiment.

Comment: @G0BLiN: This question is asking for a list of good systems, none of which (by definition) could possibly fit into an answer in their entirety. That's shopping.